# Unable to control a Table's visibility using javascript under chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have a UI that's displaying card elements which expand when clicked.

The card initially contains a table with a CSS display value of "none".
When the user clicks the card, it triggers a javascript function that changes the table's display value from "none" to "revert", which causes the table to show up.

This works just fine in Firefox, but for some reason, chrome is ignoring the code that changes the display value on the table.

```
  function toggle_card(x) {
    var expandable = document.getElementById(x);

    console.log('expandable:', expandable.style.display);
    console.log('id:', expandable.id);

    if (expandable.style.display == "none")
    {
      console.log('Try Revert');
      expandable.style.display = "revert";
    } else {
      console.log('Try None');
      expandable.style.display = "none";
    }
    console.log('finally:', expandable.style.display);
  }
```

When clicking on a card, this is the console output chrome shows:

```
expandable: none
clubhouse:634 id: tGLR.000B4002.0000D55C.0013.A387
clubhouse:637 Try Revert
clubhouse:643 finally: none
```

It looks like the function triggers correctly, identifies the current element ID and display state, but setting a new display value has no effect.  Any ideas?

Comment: Chrome doesn't support `revert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>The style `display: revert` is not a valid style. You are probably looking for the style `display: initial` to set the original style for the table</s>

**Edit**: I was not aware of the existance of the `revert` value for `display`. For cross-browser support it can be useful to check https://caniuse.com/#search=revert. That has an up-to-date list of browser support for every feature.

Because the `revert` value does not represent a valid style in Chrome, the behaviour across browsers is not properly defined. It seems to me like Chrome interprets an incorrect value for the style by simply not changing the display style.

As a demonstration:

```js
function changeDisplay() {
  var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
  switch (foo.style.display) {
    case 'none':
      console.log("The span had style == '" + foo.style.display + "'.");
      foo.style.display = 'inline';
      break;
    case 'inline':
      console.log("The span had style == '" + foo.style.display + "'.");
      foo.style.display = 'invalid';
      break;
    case 'invalid':
      console.log("The span had style == '" + foo.style.display + "'.");
      foo.style.display = 'initial';
      break;
    case 'initial':
      console.log("The span had style == '" + foo.style.display + "'.");
      foo.style.display = 'none';
      break;
    default:
      console.log("The span had style == '" + foo.style.display + "'.");
      foo.style.display = 'none';
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeDisplay()">Change display</button>

<br/><br/>

<span id="foo">Example element</span>
```

Other than this I can't help you much, because you didn't provide any working example. If this does not help, please include the HTML code as well, so that I'd be able to see what's going wrong.

Comment: I was doing my CSS editing in FireFox and wasn't aware chrome doesn't support the 'revert' value.  I used "display:table" and it works, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a link to https://caniuse.com/#search=revert, that's a useful resource when checking which browser supports what.